# Does TestCafe have a way of setting the default browser window size?

Tags: testing, browser, automation, e2e-testing, testcafe

Reading the [CLI Docs](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html), there doesn't appear to be a way to set the default browser window size.  Is there a way to do this so that each test or each test fixture doesn't have to?

I should point out that adding a `resizeWindow` call in each test, or even once per test fixture is not a scalable solution across many fixtures so the "proper" solution should/would involve some sort of config so it only needs to be set once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TestCafe does not have such an option out of the box. However, you can put the [t.resizeWindow](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/resize-window.html#setting-the-window-size) action into the [beforeEach](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/test-code-structure.html#test-hooks) test hook.

Another way is to run a browser with the special command line argument.
 
For example, the command line for Chrome:

```
testcafe "chrome '--window-size=800,600'" test.js
```

Comment: Yea, the test/test fixture option doesn't scale which is why we were looking to do it via config.  Your solution should work perfectly.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you happen to know how to do this for IE11?  Thanks.

Comment: IE11 doesn't seem to provide a similar command-line option (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/hh826025(v=vs.85)). So it looks like this approach cannot be used with the IE browser.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me, however, I had to remove the qoutes. Instead it worked this way: `chrome --window-size=1600,1200`